# Eureka TextAreaRow inputting content covered by keyboard

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

I add lots of Rows to my FormViewController，Second from the top is TextAreaRow.

```
textAreaRow = TextAreaRow(){row in
    row.textAreaHeight = TextAreaHeight.dynamic(initialTextViewHeight: 30)
    row.placeholder = "..."
}
```

But when I keep inputting something in textAreaRow, the inputed content is covered by keyboard (Demo GIF in below):

[image: Demo Gif]

You can see in the demo ,when I input 5 and go on,it's covered by keyboard.

How to fix it???

Could I scroll textAeraRow when it's covered by keyboard?How to do that???
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for this is on the `onChange` event of the TextAreaRow

```
.onChange({ [weak self] row in
      self?.view.layoutIfNeeded() //or self?.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```